# How can I change more than a date format in a unique format with a single php function?

Tags: php, function, date-format

I would like to understand how to change different date formats into a single format using a php function. After trying in every way, i wasn't able to solve this puzzle. I always just used the following code in my custom function.php smoothly:

```
/* Change date format for coupon */
function change_date_format($x) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $x);
    $x = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    return $x;
}
```

In this way i can convert the format 'j-M-Y' in the format 'Y-m-d'. The problem is that now i need to convert not only the date format 'j-M-Y', but also other formats (for example, i've to convert date format 'j-M-Y' and date format 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP' in date format 'Y-m-d'. I tried to combine different logic functions but system gives me error.

Thanks to all of you who try to help me...

Comment: Why not just try this and see if it works for the formats you need: `$date = new DateTime($x);`

Comment: AbraCadaver i've tried your solution and it seems to work, but if I have the date format 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP' the output I get is for example: 2016-06-30T23:59:59+02:00. I wish that in such cases the output is only 'Y-m-d' without T23:59:59+02:00. Thank you very much

Comment: You still have to do `$x = $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` class is pretty good at parsing different formats without `createFromFormat()`.  If the formats you have are supported ([Supported Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)) then just let it create based on the in-built logic.  If `$x = '2016-06-30T23:59:59+02:00'` then the `DateTime` class handles this just fine:

```
function change_date_format($x) {
    $date = new DateTime($x);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Really I do not know how to thank you ... Thank you so much, you have solved my riddle!

Answer (score 1):

Add an input parameter to your function called: `$inputFormat` and use this instead `'j-M-Y'`, so you should specify always the input format. You can specify a default format for input.

```
/**
 * Return with a normal format of any date by given format
 * Default format is j-M-Y if no input format given
 * 
 * @param string $dateString
 * @param string $inputFormat
 * @return string
 */
function change_date_format($dateString, $inputFormat = 'j-M-Y') {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat, $dateString);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo change_date_format('23-05-2016', 'd-m-Y');
echo change_date_format('05/23/2016', 'm/d/Y');
```

Comment: Thank you Iolka, but with your code the system gives me: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: Then your `DateTime::createFromFormat` has failed. Maybe you sent bad format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional parameter as follows:

```
/*Change date format for coupon*/
function change_date_format($x, $dateFormat) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $x);
    $x = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    return $x;
}
```

Comment: Sujeet thank you, i've tried your solution but system gives me:
Warning: Missing argument 2 for change_date_format()
Notice: Undefined variable: dateFormat
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: I saw that the issue is solved for you, but can you please share the function call you used? I believe you didn't pass in the required parameters..