# Php function - How can I change any date format in a particular format (including unix timestamp format)?

Tags: php, function, date-format, unix-timestamp

a few days ago I asked for a solution that would allow me to get a particular date format, starting from any other date format. The solution that I'm using is marked as the best answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392036/how-can-i-change-more-than-a-date-format-in-a-unique-format-with-a-single-php-fu).
By using this solution I have not encountered problems, but I find myself today to cope with another little problem. In practice, I also need to convert the format date unix timestamp (in milliseconds) in the format 'Y-m-d'. I tried several solutions but I have problems if I try to combine them with this function:

```
function change_date_format($x) {
    $date = new DateTime($x);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

I trust in your help, 
thank you so much

Comment: share some example that you are trying to convert ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change more than a date format in a unique format with a single php function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392036/how-can-i-change-more-than-a-date-format-in-a-unique-format-with-a-single-php-fu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [DateTime object documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) would help you

```
function change_date_format_from_unix_timestamp($x) {
    // convert from milliseconds to seconds
    $x = floor($x / 1000);
    // convert timestamp to DateTime object
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $x);
    // return formatted date
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
function change_date_format($x){
  if(is_numeric($x)){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp($x);
  } else {
    $date = new DateTime($x);
  }

  return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Now for the timestamp contains miliseconds, just devide by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.
You can use a date format and unix timestamp directly in phps date function.

```
function change_date_format($x){
   return date('Y-m-d', $x/1000);
}
```